# Reading Emails in .NetCoreApp Version 3.1 (C#) on Exchange Server

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

Has anyone tried reading mails from an exchange server with an .netcoreapp version 3.1?

I tried several things and I can't get it to work.

I tried it with MailKit

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect("exchange..", port);
                

                    client.Authenticate("uname", "pass");

                    client.Inbox.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                    var uids = client.Inbox.Search(MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.All);

                    foreach (var uid in uids)
                    {
                        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                    }
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

I tried it with the Microsoft.Exchange.WebService package. But this one only supports Exchange Server from 2007 to 2013.

What should I do? I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the version of Exchange trying to read from?

Comment: Exchange Server 2016 CU15

Comment: What's the problem? Did you get an error? What error is it? If you get an authentication error, no matter what library you use you won't be able to read emails. Perhaps you're using the wrong port, or using an unencrypted connection when TLS is required. Or trying to connect from an IP that isn't allowed to connect at all

Comment: Which Exchange version are you using? Local or cloud? Is IMAP enabled on the server to begin with? Or POP3? Exchange doesn't use some obscure protocol, it's still an emails server. Email servers don't allow just anyone to connect though, to prevent spam.

Comment: Exchange Server 2016 CU15 15.1.1913.5. It is Local. IMAP is enabled. If I use a SecureSocketOption in the client.connect this error apears `MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException: Syntax error in IMAP server greeting. Unexpected token: [atom: 220]`

Answer (score 0):

Use Exchange Web Services (EWS) Managed API, that will allow you to specify the version for Exchange Server.

Comment: I work in a company and I can't change the Exchange Server right now..

Comment: what are the port numbers you tried? check this solution :-https://forum.uipath.com/t/reading-pop-imap-email-error-220/17338

Comment: I already have a working Smtp connection with System.Net.Mail. The Port is 25 and it should work